# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'place_id'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I was trying to do the users-following-schools function of our website, and I made a relationship table (named 'follow') like this

```
class Follow(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'follow'
    follower_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)  
    followed_id = db.Column(db.String(50), 
    db.ForeignKey('school.place_id'),primary_key=True)  
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

and the relevant attributes of user and school model is:

```
 class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
   __tablename__ = 'user'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   followed = db.relationship('Follow',
                                foreign_keys=[Follow.follower_id],
                                backref=db.backref('follower', lazy='joined'),
                                lazy='dynamic',cascade='all,delete-orphan')
 class School(db.Model):
    _tablename_ = 'school'
    place_id = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
    followers = db.relationship('Follow',  
                           foreign_keys=[Follow.followed_id],
                           backref=db.backref('followed,lazy=joined'),  # corresponding followed_id
                           lazy='dynamic',
                           cascade='all, delete-orphan')
```

Besides, I wrote three methods that relevant to following behavior in User model

```
def follow(self, school):                          
        if not self.is_following(school):
            f = Follow(follower=self, followed=school)    
            db.session.add(f)                           
            db.session.commit()


def unfollow(self, school):                       
        f = self.followed.filter_by(followed_id=school.place_id).first()       
        if f is not None:
            db.session.delete(f)
            db.session.commit()


def is_following(self,school):
        return self.followed.filter_by(followed_id=school.place_id).first() is not None
```

and I also wrote followings in my main/views.py

```
@main.route('/follow/<official_school_name>')
@login_required
# @permission_required(Permission.USER_LIKE)
def follow(official_school_name):
    school = School.query.filter_by(official_school_name=official_school_name).first()
    if school is None:
        flash('Invalid school name.')
        return redirect(url_for('.index'))
    if current_user.is_following(school):
        flash('You have already followed this school.')
        return redirect(url_for('.school', official_school_name=school.official_school_name, roll_number=school.roll_number))
    current_user.follow(user)
    flash('You are not following %s.' % official_school_name)
    return redirect(url_for('.school', official_school_name=school.official_school_name, roll_number=school.roll_number))
```

Finally, I just made an unformal button for testing the follow function.

```
 <a href="{{ url_for('.follow', official_school_name=school.official_school_name, roll_number=school.roll_number) }}"
        class = "btn btn-primary">Follow</a>
```

However, when I click the Follow button, it shows the error:

```
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
Open an interactive python shell in this framereturn self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\contrib\fixers.py", line 152, in __call__
return self.app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "E:\Project0619\ProjectTest\Code\app\main\views.py", line 197, in follow
current_user.follow(user)
File "E:\Project0619\ProjectTest\Code\app\models\User.py", line 99, in follow
if not self.is_following(school):
File "E:\Project0619\ProjectTest\Code\app\models\User.py", line 113, in is_following
return self.followed.filter_by(followed_id=school.place_id).first() is not None
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'place_id'
```

I tried to change the 'is_following' function as:

```
 def is_following(self,school):
            return self.followed.filter_by(followed_id=school.id).first() is not None
```

then the other error appeared:

```
 File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\contrib\fixers.py", line 152, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\kjhk\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 261, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Project0619\ProjectTest\Code\app\main\views.py", line 194, in follow
    if current_user.is_following(school):
  File "E:\Project0619\ProjectTest\Code\app\models\User.py", line 113, in is_following
    return self.followed.filter_by(followed_id=school.id).first() is not None
AttributeError: 'School' object has no attribute 'id'
```

That proves the second argus(School.id) can refer to the 'School' model, but anyone can help me to answer why the first error appeared? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error: `AttributeError: 'School' object has no attribute 'id'` does not prove very much about your other issue. Looking carefully at each call stack tells us more about what is happening:

The first call uses `if not self.is_following(school)` as its entry point, while the second call uses `if current_user.is_following(school)`. I can see this from the Tracebacks you posted.

In the second, you define school as:

```
school = School.query.filter_by(official_school_name=official_school_name).first()
```

And in latter case, `school` actually is an instance of the `School` class.

However, in the first example, the school arg is being passed in as `user`:

```
current_user.follow(user)<-----
```

... and `user` is apparently defined in your code as type `function`. You could test this by printing or returning `type(user)`.

Pass `school` to the first call and that should stop the `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'place_id'` issue.